# JavaScript - Horizontal list animation glitch (IE8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

So when I attempt this code:

```
function doMove() {
   var left = $('#navContainer').css('margin-left');
   left = parseInt(left) + 1;
   $('#navContainer').css('margin-left', left + 'px'); // show frame
   setTimeout(doMove,20); // call doMove() in 20 msec
}
```

On this:

```
#navlist li
{
   display: inline;
   list-style-type: none;
   padding-right: 0px;
   padding-left: 0px;
   margin-right: -2px;
   margin-left: -2px;
}

<div class="floatIt" id="smallNavContainer">
   <div id="navContainer">
      <ul id="navlist">
         <li><a><img id="btn9" src="xxx.png" alt="???"/></a></li>
         <li><a><img id="btn10" src="xxx.png" alt="???"/></a></li>
         <li><a><img id="btn11" src="xxx.png" alt="???"/></a></li>
         <li><a><img id="btn1" src="xxx.png" alt="???"/></a></li>
         <li><a><img id="btn2" src="xxx.png" alt="???"/></a></li>
         <li><a><img id="btn3"  src="xxx.png" alt="???"/></a></li>
         <li><a><img id="btn4" src="xxx.png" alt="???"/></a></li>
         <li><a><img id="btn5" src="xxx.png" alt="???"/></a></li>
         <li><a><img id="btn6" src="xxx.png" alt="???"/></a></li>
         <li><a><img id="btn7" src="xxx.png" alt="???"/></a></li>
         <li><a><img id="btn8" src="xxx.png" alt="???"/></a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

It does animate to the left with one main issue, each time an image leaves the view of smallNavContainer it jumps to the left and leaves a smaller chunk of blank space in it's place.

I have tried jQuery animate and it still gives me the same issue.

EDIT - Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xReJT/9/
Under IE8 it jumps under chrome the image just disappears prematurely

Comment: can't you use jQuery.animate() ?

Comment: I get the same issue when using jquery animate.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xReJT/9/ Under IE8 it jumps under chrome the image just disappears prematurely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is that you animate the margin. For my opinion animation is more intuitive and leads to better results if you use two nested div containers and animate position style properties like top and left.

The outer one has a defined width and height, sets overflow to hidden and its position must not be static. The inner, also not static positioned, is the one you animate, normally one uses the top and left property. This inner div can be the container for every kind of html which than can be animated.

good luck…

Comment: This. I was using margin-left to offset the inner div initially so the left wasn't working for me and I went to animating with margin-left because I didn't think it would work differently... Well it did.   Thanks for catching my bone head maneuver.